# Attempt to prove the $∀d∀x∀y (d | x ∧ d | y ∧ x ≤ y → d | y- x)$ property of the “divides” relation for non-negative integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, proof-verification, predicate-logic, formal-proofs

I am attempting to prove the $∀d∀x∀y (d | x ∧ d | y ∧ x ≤ y → d | y- x)$ property of the “divides” relation for non-negative integers, but am having a little difficulty and am hoping someone can help.

I have access to the standard rules of natural deduction, the following axioms:
[image]

and the following useful formulas:

[image]

---

Here is my attempt so far:

[image]

Comment: Not clear what you are asking... The long "list" has been produced by way of some proof assistant ? If so, the last formula (53) is what you have to prove: thus, it must be correct (if the proof assistant works correctly). If not, how do you produced it ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The OP is using JAPE, a proof writing/checking assistant.  The ... between lines 33 and 34 means that there is still a gap in the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key formula you will have to use is:

$\forall x \forall y \forall z (z \not = 0 \rightarrow (x\cdot z \le y\cdot z \rightarrow x \le y))$

So, you will need to first consider the special case where $a=0$, but in that case you can easily show that it must be the case that $a1=0$ and $a2=0$, and it is also easy to show that $0|0-0$ so you're done.

So then you can consider $a \not = 0$, and s0 you have:

1. $a \not = 0$
2. $a|a1$
3. $a|a2$
4. $a1 \le a2$
5. $a1 = a3\cdot a$
6. $a2 = a4\cdot a$

So then using some = Elim's:

6. $a3\cdot a \le a4 \cdot a$

And now you use the key formula to get:

7. $a3\cdot a \le a4 \cdot a \rightarrow a3 \le a4$
8. $a3 \le a4$  (6,7)

and you already have the rest.

Comment: Thanks so much :) I managed to finish it with your steps I never thought of splitting on 0.

Comment: @Brams28 Would you be able to tell me which axioms/useful formulas I need to be using to prove $∀ d. ∀ x. (x ≠ 0 ∧ d | x → d ≤ x)$ ?

Comment: @MarkDonaghue Ah, that's great you were able to finish the proof! OK, for the other one ... I would think the key one there is one of the Peano Axioms: $\forall x \forall y x\cdot s(y) = (x \cdot y) + x$, since if $d$ devided nonzero $x$, then $x = d\cdot y$ for some nonzero $y$, hence ... Oh!  You probably need a 'predecessor' theorem that says that $\forall y (y \not = 0 \rightarrow \exists z y = s(z))$ ... anyway, if you have that, then $x = d \cdot s(z) = (d \cdot z) + d$ and hence $d \le x$.